# What file has the array that outputs the magento version (Magento ver. 1.13.1.0) in the admin panel

Tags: upgrade

I've seen the file before but i can't seem to find it atm. I just upgraded from 1.13 to 1.14 but the version didn't change in the admin panel footer area. Now when i did this upgrade on my staging site a month ago it all went smoothly and it updated the admin footer section aw well.

I followed all the same steps i did on stage for production and when i check the stable software running in the magento connect manager it's identical to stage in what's running. 1.14.

it's driving me crazy that the footer didn't update in admin. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The footer in the admin panel is located in `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/page/footer.phtml.`

In there, it calls `Mage::getVersion()`.

The `Mage` class is located in `app/Mage.php`

In that class, there is the method `getVersion()`, which calls `getVersionInfo()` which returns an array of the version you have installed.

It looks like this:

```
public static function getVersionInfo()
    {
        return array(
            'major'     => '1',
            'minor'     => '14',
            'revision'  => '0',
            'patch'     => '0',
            'stability' => '',
            'number'    => '',
        );
    }
```

I hope this helps.